# Any way for Wordpress to just return a do_action from add_action

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm confused as to how `add_action` and `do_action` work, I did some research on the [Function_Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) page of Wordpress, but still having issues getting it to work. The `add_action` and `do_action` are on different pages of the server.

```
$ref = '12323123213';

add_action('add_ref','add_ref_function',10,1);

function add_ref_function ( $ref ) {
   echo '<h2>Ref: ' . $ref . '</h2>';
}

do_action('add_ref');
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old, but maybe my solution will help for someone.

```
function print_ref(){
    $ref = '12323123213';
    return $ref;
}

add_action('add_ref','add_ref_function');
function add_ref_function() {
   echo '<h2>Ref: '. print_ref() .'</h2>';
}

do_action('add_ref');
```

Answer (score 0):

`add_action()` takes the identification of a function, in your case `add_ref_function`, and puts it into a list of functions to be called whenever anybody calls `do_action()`.

It basically registers your function as a callback. Then, later, whenever any part of WordPress invokes `do_action('add_ref')` your function will get called at priority `10` with just one parameter.

This lets you do all kinds of stuff in your code. For example, if you use `do_action('init',myfunction,10,1)` you can get your function called right after WordPress has finished initializing everything in its core. This is great for initializing a plugin or something in a theme, for example.

Comment: Thank you, what would be the best route to take if I need to just return a $string to other page?

Answer (score 0):

`do_action` calls all functions attached to it with `add_action`. In your example, the value $ref would not get used as the input parameter, unless you add it to the `do_action` call:

```
do_action( 'add_ref', $ref );
```